# jquery ajax responseText not working in ie9

Tags: jquery, ajax

The following bit of code works great in everything but IE.  In IE, the alert of `data.responseText` is saying undefined.  But in all other browsers, it returns the correct data.

What am I missing?  It works great in Firefox, Chrome, Safari, etc.

If I change `data.responseText` to just data, I get `[object Object]`.

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "",
    data: "command=loadComments&id=" + song_id,
    dataType: "html",
    complete: function(data) {
        loading.fadeOut('slow');

        $("#comments-list").fadeIn('slow', function() {
            $("#comments-list").html(data.responseText);
            alert(data.responseText);
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: try data = eval(data)..first line in function...and change complete to success..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `success` as the reason is probably that it's throwing an error in IE. Also add an `error` callback to check what the problem is. Text encoding, for example, is a common IE-only error in AJAX calls.

Comment: try using `url: "./"` instead of the empty string.

Comment: Thanks for your help matt3141.  With updating the url, no error is thrown, but it doesn't look like success is even thrown now (because loading.fadeOut no longer happens).  Still works great in other browsers.

Comment: was `./` the intended url? Maybe try specifying a certain file.

Comment: It is.  And it is working correctly on a number of other browsers.  IE is still being a pain. :/

Comment: So if neither `success` or `error` are firing, is complete even firing? I didn't think it was possible that neither would fire.

Comment: Ok, an update.  Success is being met after-all, it's just occurring very slowly.  Not sure why that is; perhaps the environment I'm developing in.   But thanks much, really appreciate the help!

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `.complete()` you can try with `.success()` function.

**CODE**

```
   success: function(data){
        loading.fadeOut('slow');
        $("#comments-list").fadeIn('slow', function() {
            $("#comments-list").html(data.responseText);
            alert(data.responseText);
        });
    }
```

From jQuery doc:

> **success(data, textStatus, jqXHR)**
>
> A function to be called if the request succeeds. The function gets passed three arguments: The data
> returned from the server, formatted according to the dataType
> parameter; a string describing the status; and the jqXHR (in jQuery
> 1.4.x, XMLHttpRequest) object.

and

> **complete(jqXHR, textStatus)**
>
> A function to be called when the request finishes (after success and
> error callbacks are executed). The function gets passed two arguments:
> The jqXHR (in jQuery 1.4.x, XMLHTTPRequest) object and a string
> categorizing the status of the request ("success", "notmodified",
> "error", "timeout", "abort", or "parsererror").

Comment: But this seem not answer why? `responseText` is a property of `jqXHR`.

Comment: @xdazz I know Sir, but `success()` is reliable then `complete()` and with no issue with different browsers